# SQL Server Permissions to Script Server Logins (But Not Alter Them)

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a script that tries to recreate part of a database.  Part of that is to script out the logins that are used with that database.

I am trying to find a "cannot do harm" level of permission for this to run as.

Basically it needs to be able to see all the server logins to script them out (except passwords of course).  But it needs to not have permissions to add, alter or delete anything on the server.  Just script.

I looked at the roles and permissions for the server level, and I am not finding anything like that.

**Does SQL Server have server level read only permissions for logins?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does SQL Server have server level read only permissions for logins?

Yes, but it is not for ANY login, it is on a granular level, for each login:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-principal-permissions-transact-sql

```
USE master;  
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::EricKurjan TO RMeyyappan   
GO
```

The downside is that you have to grant view definition for each login and every time a new login is created. For new logins, you could create a server DDL trigger which grants VIEW DEFINITION permission for the newly created login to your login (or better create a custom server role for this)

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_for_create_login
ON ALL SERVER   
FOR CREATE_LOGIN  
AS
BEGIN   
    declare @newlogin sysname = quotename(EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','sysname'));
    declare @sql nvarchar(200) = 'GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON LOGIN::'+ @newlogin +' TO public'; --<-- public just for testing.. change public to a custom server role
    exec(@sql);
END
GO
```

Another option (not tested but logically it should work) would be to create a login from a certificate or asymmetric key, add the cert/asym login to the securityadmin role and then sign your script (the one which reads logins) with the cert/asym key.